# How to clear the textarea after form submission

Tags: php, html

I am new to php! I have a contact form. I need to clear all the fields after the submission of the form. The textarea doesnt get cleared with the form when the form is submitted. Here is the code. Please tell me where need I change the code. Please help me how to clear the textarea.

```
<?php


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = "";

    if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't type in your name. <br />";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
      if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){ 
      $error .= "The e-mail address you entered is not valid. <br/>";
      }
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't type in an e-mail address. <br />";
    }





    if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't type in a message. <br />";
    }


    if(($_POST['code']) == $_SESSION['code']) { 
    $code = $_POST['code'];
    } else { 
    $error .= "The captcha code you entered does not match. Please try again. <br />";    
    }



    if (empty($error)) {
    $from = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>';
    $to = "abc@gmail.com";
    $subject = " contact form message";
    $content = $name . " has sent you a message: \n 

 Email:  $email \n   

 Message:  $message " ;

    $success = "<b>Thank you! Your message has been sent!</b>";
    mail($to,$subject,$content,$from);

    }
    }
    ?>

              <div id="contactForm">



                <?php
      if (!empty($error)) {
      echo '<p class="error"><strong>Your message was NOT sent<br/> The following error(s) returned:</strong><br/>' . $error . '</p>';
      } elseif (!empty($success)) {
      echo $success;
      }
    ?>

            <form action="contact.php" method="post"  style="margin-top:20px;">
              <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form Submission" />
              <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="contact.php" />

              <label style="font-size:14px;">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" value="" style="margin-left:36px;" <?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) { echo $_POST['name']; } ?>" />
                <br/>
                <br/>

              <label style="font-size:14px;">E-mail:</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" value="" style="margin-left:30px;"<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" />
                <br/>
                <br/>




              <label style="float:left; margin-right:10px; font-size:14px">Comment:</label>
              <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" wrap="hard">
                <?php  if (isset($_POST['message'])) { echo $_POST['message']; } ?>
              </textarea>
                <br/>
                <br/>

              <label style="margin-left:2px;">
                <img src="captcha.php" style="margin-top:10px;">
              </label>
              <input type="text" name="code" style="margin-left:23px;">
                <br /> <br />

                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" />

              </form>
```

Comment: Those label elements are useless. They aren't associated with any form control. Look up how the `for` attribute works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the code you have that explicitly fills it with the previous data.

```
<?php  if (isset($_POST['message'])) { echo $_POST['message']; } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" wrap="hard">
   <?php  if (isset($_POST['message'])) { echo $_POST['message']; } ?>
</textarea>
```

A php line between those two basically says that if there is a POST request with a parameter message, write that message there.

In human words, if a form is submitted, then a message appears there.

If you don't want a message to be there when a submit is invoked, then just remove that php line. Otherwise, please update your answer and try give more details